# CondaError: No writable package cache directories found in conda-pkgs

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter, conda

When I try to create a virtual environment for my jupyter notebook or install any packages in it or try to update conda.

```
conda create -n virenv python=3.6
```

I get an error

```
CondaError: No writable package cache directories found in
('C:\\ProgramData\\conda-pkgs',)
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was due to some permission error I guess. So I created a dedicated folder in my user directory as a package cache, then added it to the pkgs_dirs configuration option (conda config --add pkgs_dirs dir_name). We may need to manually add the default cache(s) back since I think customizing excludes them (check conda config --show pkgs_dirs before and after).

Answer (score 0):

That might happen if you write **no** at the end of the anaconda installation,
resulting in permission issues and conda enviroment not being activated.
as well as you can't create more enviroments.

Solution is :

```
sudo chmod a+w /home/path/to/.conda
```

example

```
sudo chmod a+w /home/yourusername/.conda
```

Cheers.